# Discretizing the parameters as a regularisation method

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, nonlinear-regression, regularization

I'm thinking of cases where generalisation can be improved if the parameter space was discretised instead of continuous during the fitting stage. It is easy to think of contrived examples where this is true (see the below example), but I'm wondering if there's been any research into the theory behind this and the practical considerations. Also, are there any well researched methods to regularise regression models through discretisation?

Here is an extreme example. Suppose we have a function $f(x_0 | \theta_0)$ which we fit through minimisation of MSE given a choice of $\theta_0 \in [0,1]$. Suppose given in sample data, the MSE has values:

$MSE = \begin{cases}  0.1, & \text{if}\ \theta_0 \in [0,0.5] \\ 0.5, & \text{if}\ \theta_0 \in (0.5,0.995]\cup [0.998,1.0] \\ 0.099, & \text{if}\ \theta_0 \in (0.995,0.998) \end{cases}$

If this is a problem in a domain that's known to be noisy, I would want to choose solution $\theta_0 = 0.25$ instead of the global in-sample minimum at $\theta_0 \in (0.995,0.998)$.

The reason being that in the presence of sampling variance in MSE itself, I not only want to find the minimum, but I want to find a large contiguous area in the parameter space within which the MSE has near-minimum values, so that we can expect decent generalisation even if the MSE is slightly different upon resampling (i.e. on the out of sample dataset).

Discretisation seems to be one way to achieve this (to push the solution towards long valleys instead of spiky peaks; e.g. sampling from $[0.0,0.1,...,1.0]$), aside from another approach of looking at the mean MSE value in a hypercube around a proposed solution which is infeasible with expensive function evaluations, or an even more hack-ey approach of actually terminating an optimisation at an easy to find local optima instead of the global optima since the ease with which it's found may be correlated with sufficient contiguity of parameters that result in similar cost evaluations. Now all this is stuff conjured up in my imagination and is in no way rigorous, I'm sure there's much better approaches. I haven't yet encountered a good treatment of this concept, I'm very thankful for any directions you can point me towards. I am of course already familiar with mainstream regularisation approaches (L1, L2, etc), I'm focused on discretisation especially in non-linear models.

Comment: Discrete optimization is generally harder than continuous optimization, and the scenario in your example could be as easily handled by bagging.  You might take a look at the neural network literature on early termination and learning rates. Those guys are the kings and queens of effective, yet ad hoc ways to improve optimization of multi-modal objectives.  Be sure to answer your own question if you find anything!